# Application for debugging SQLNCLI Connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlncli

I am having difficulty getting an application that uses SQL native client to connect to my SQL Server, which up until this point functioned just fine. SQL Profiler on the source server indicates my troublesome application isn't even connecting to the server. I can't find anything in the applications logs or the Windows Event logs.

I would like to independently prove that the issue is not SQL configuration on the machine by using another application to connect. I have tried ODBC with the SQLNCLI Driver, and it works fine but I'm not sure if that is the same as code that directly uses SQLNCLI. The matter is even more confused by the fact there are 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the driver available on my server. Are there any stand alone or command line utilities that I can use to emulate an applications connection to SQL and analyse any debug messages I might get back.

I'm on a server 2008 x64 machine, connecting to the SQL Server 2008 x64 Mirror.

Comment: You cannot connect to a Mirror Database as it is always in `Restoring State` :), You will have to create a Snapshot of that mirror database and connect to that.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to say mirroring, I'm always trying to connect to the Primary database.